# create source file inside a folder within a package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a package where I'm putting all of my code.

However, I would now like to create a folder\package inside of that package like a child package.

I was unable to make a child package in eclise by folllowing the convention **ExistingPackagename.ChildPackagename**. So I went to my file system, made the desired structure. When I refresh, I see that my file system has the structure I want, but on eclipse, it still shows the Parent and the child packages at the same level. It shows my packages in the same level as

1. Parent
2. Parent.Child1
3. Parent.Child2
4. Parent.Child3

Comment: Please clarify; what is your *question*? Modify a class in `Child1` and change the package name to `Parent.Child1`.

Comment: Are your folders empty? If so, Eclipse *flattens* package names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reality there is no such thing as a sub-package in Java - each package is a completely separate entity, with the names being seemingly hierarchical only for convenience. For example, items with default visibility are not visible in sub-packages, despite what one might expect.

If your problem has more to do with presentation and aesthetics than substance, then perhaps what you are looking for is the hierarchical package presentation setting in the Eclipse Package Explorer: click on the little downward triangle/arrow at the top right of the package explorer and select "Hierarchical" in the "Package presentation" submenu:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably in the "Project Explorer" view. Select `Window -> Show view -> Package Explorer` 
Also, you don't have to create child packages from the file system. Just right click the current package, select `New -> Package` [image: adding Package]